# auto generation of numbers in c#. Eg.E001,E002

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I want auto generation of numbers in c#. Actually i have EmpCode with E and C followed by 3digit no. I have two text boxes. one box is for selecting  E or C and another one for number which i want automatically generate like E001,E002

Comment: Take the last number from the table and append E or C accordingly in your C# code

Comment: This is a duplicate of [your deleted question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30885515/1324033), please read [ask] before posting again

Comment: `int n = int.Parse(txtNum.text);string s="E"+n.ToString("D3");`

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> numbers = new List<String>();
string code = "E"; //Or "C"
for(int i = 0; i <= 999; i++)
{
    numbers.Add(String.Format("{0}{1:000}", code, i));
}
```

Will create E000 - E999 or C000 - C999.